# What is the syntax for resolving Thenable<'t> in F# using fable?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, fable-f#

I'm working on a vscode extension written in F# using Fable to compile to javascript. Many of the api's return a promise. What is the syntax for for resolving a promise that have return types such as `Thenable<string[]>` for F#?

Here is an example of many of the api's for vscode: [vscode api](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing with the syntax, I was able to figure it out with the clue that rmunn gave with converting the Thenable to Promise.

```
module PromiseUtils =
  let success (a : 'T -> 'R) (pr : Promise<'T>) : Promise<'R> =
      pr?``then`` (unbox a) |> unbox

  let toPromise (a : Thenable<'T>) = a |> unbox<Promise<'T>>

  let toThenable (a : Promise<'T>) = a |> unbox<Thenable<'T>>
```

Using the utility module above, I was able to convert the functions that return Thenable to Promises so they could be resloved.

```
  let result = commands.getCommands ()
               |> PromiseUtils.toPromise
               |> PromiseUtils.success (fun item -> 
                  let firstOne = item.Item 1
                  console.log(firstOne))
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at how Ionide does it:

https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-helpers/blob/fable/Helpers.fs
https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-helpers/blob/fable/Fable.Import.VSCode.fs

Basically, it looks like Ionide almost ignored the existence of `Thenable<T>` and converted every API call to a `Promise<T>` in their Fable bindings. They do have a pair of `toPromise` and `toThenable` functions in [Helpers.fs](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-helpers/blob/b81a80ede2179222a5639cf866423d9bc6c2f0b4/src/Helpers.fs#L85), but I don't see those being used anywhere in the entire https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp repository.

I don't have any personal experience with Fable, so if this isn't enough to answer your question, hopefully someone else will chime in with more information.

Comment: Yeah, I did see those examples. However, I didn't actually see how the promises were actually being resolved (like you mentioned they weren't being used) because the types don't match up. I must be missing something.